# Why are my divs disappearing when I use flex-direction?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently working on my webpage's responsiveness and have implemented flexbox for the positioning of my page's elements. The issue that I am experiencing is that when I use 'flex-direction: column' in my media query, the divs disappear upon the browser being resized. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
  #blue {
  background-color: #57afb5;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#dark-green {
  background-color: #29914c;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#green {
  background-color: #91e3ad;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #c98a32;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 2%;
}


/* responsive web design*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /*end of responsive web design*/
```

```html
<div class='main-content'>
  <div id='Navbar_Link-Toggle' style='font-size: 20px'>
    <i id='main' class='fas fa-bars'></i>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='Navbar'>
      <a class='links' href=''>FOOD</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>FUN</a>
      <img id='center-logo' src='img/SAMO.png'>
      <a class='links' href=''>HISTORY</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>LOCATION</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='header'>
    <img id='food' src='img/food.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='top'>
  <div id='blue'></div>
  <div id='dark-green'></div>
</div>
<div id='bottom'>
  <div id='green'></div>
  <div id='orange'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-direction: column` is not found in your example, please update your question with the code that is "breaking". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #top and #bottom divs have no height. You could give them a hight. I.E `#top, #bottom { hight: 700px; }`

Alternatively, use `display: block;` as illustrated in the example below.

Side note: When I have missing elements, I'll sometimes throw a `border: solid red 2px;` on them to better visualize what is happening. Hope that helps for next time!

```css
#blue {
  background-color: #57afb5;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#dark-green {
  background-color: #29914c;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#green {
  background-color: #91e3ad;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #c98a32;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 2%;
}


/* responsive web design*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #top,
  #bottom {
    display: block;
  }
}
  /*end of responsive web design*/
```

```html
<div class='main-content'>
  <div id='Navbar_Link-Toggle' style='font-size: 20px'>
    <i id='main' class='fas fa-bars'></i>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='Navbar'>
      <a class='links' href=''>FOOD</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>FUN</a>
      <img id='center-logo' src='img/SAMO.png'>
      <a class='links' href=''>HISTORY</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>LOCATION</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='header'>
    <img id='food' src='img/food.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='top'>
  <div id='blue'></div>
  <div id='dark-green'></div>
</div>
<div id='bottom'>
  <div id='green'></div>
  <div id='orange'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Fixed my problem.